# Laravel Spatie Laravel-Navigation Route Error

Tags: php, laravel, plugins

I'm trying to make the Spatie Laravel-Navitation plugins to work on my project in Laravel 9.1.0
[Spatie Laravel Navigation](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-navigation)

So far I did :

1. Install the plugin with composer
2. add the plugin to the config/app.php provider

   App\Providers\NavigationProvider::class,
3. Add the alias in the config/app.php aliases

   'Navigation' => Spatie\Navigation\NavigationServiceProvider::class,
4. From what I understand I create a new provider

   php artisan make:provider NavigationProvider
5. Inside the provider I add to the top

   use Spatie\Navigation\Navigation;
6. Inside the handle function I add this

   app(Navigation::class)
   ->add('dashboard', route('dashboard'));

I have the following error since:

```
Route [dashboard] not defined.
```

In my routes/web.php I have the following route.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('pages.dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Any Idea what I miss.
Any tips also on how I will use this in the blade after making the route portion work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a thought, is your `dashboard` route inside a group with a prefix?

Comment: If you run `php artisan route:list` does the route show with a name?

Comment: Try to run `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: @FluxCoder
 Yes it's inside the Route::group(
    ['middleware' => ['auth']],
    function () {

Comment: @FluxCoder
php artisan route:list

  GET|HEAD        / .............................................................................. dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe found the issue but I'm not sure it's the most elegant way to do this.

In my controller boot function I did this :

```
    $this->app->booted(function () {
        app(Navigation::class)
        ->add('dashboard', route('dashboard'));
    });
    view()->composer('*',function($view) {
        $view->with('navigation', app(Navigation::class)->tree() );
        $view->with('breadcrumbs', app(Navigation::class)->breadcrumbs() );
    });
```